# img max-width 100%, overscale img to fill div

Tags: css

I'm using `max-width: 100%` on an img within a div, to have the image scale automatically as the browser window is adjusted.

Is there any way I can make the image 'over-scale / enlarge' over its initial size, with the same scale, if the div's width is larger than the img width?

Thanks

Comment: If you turn it into a `background-image` on an element instead of using an `img` you can use `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need `max-width: 100%;`. Just use `width: 100%;` instead. Example:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}

<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500?image=9" />
```

The above kitten image will **always** scale up or down to be 100% as wide as its parent.

---

You can get a sort of conditional logic with media queries. In this example below, we have a headline and a 500px wide image. The image has `max-width: 100%;`. **And** there's a media query which says that when the viewport is more than 500px wide, the image's **width** should be 100% the width of its parent (and make the body background grey to identify when this media query applies).

HTML:

```
<h1>Pellentesque habitant morbi</h1>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500?image=10" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  body  {
    background-color: #AAA;
  }  
  img {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Thus, when inside a wide viewport, the image is as wide as that viewport.

---

Alternately, try making the image a background image, and then use CSS's `background-size: cover;`:

```
#image {
  background: #D84E51 url(http://placekitten.com/800/800?image=10) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```